# Is there a compact way of identifying/storing classes?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there something like an integer that can be used to store and retrieve `Class` objects (for example, the index of the class in a public list of loaded classes)? I would like to store classes in files while keeping them as compact as possible, and I don't know if storing the name of the class is the only viable route.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Using the full class name seems the only viable option though.

Comment: @GaëlJ I am trying to make a way to serialize objects into bytestreams. I know it's already been done but I want to see if I can manage as I'm still semi-new to Java (but still somewhat competent).

Comment: Do you mean store *instances* of classes? I mean, you can serialize most anything, including a map of key -> values, but... it's unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: You can serialize and deserialize using whatever mechanism you want as long as you maintain enough information to deserialize.

Comment: @DaveNewton Something that can be easily retrieved from a class instance and can be used to get the class back.

Comment: You could try reflectively accessing the field `classes` of `ClassLoader`.

Comment: @fluffyyboii I don't understand what "Something that can be easily retrieved from a class instance and can be used to get the class back" means. You need all of the class data and the name of the class, whatever that looks like. There are many ways this can be done; searching the web for something like "compact java serialization" you'll find a number of starting points.